# Oracle Date stored as a number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I know there are a lot of date conversion threads, but I haven't seen this particular one.

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to pull a Timestamp field that has been stored as a number.

It's currently stored like this (20131203164906).  I need to export it like this (12/03/2013 0:00).

This is what I have so far, but no combination I've tried seems to work.  I've really tried before asking.

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TABLE.timestamp,'dd-mm-rr'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
From XXXX.TABLE
WHERE ROWNUM < 10;
```

Yes, I know that oracle Datetimes should never be stored as strings/numbers.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format mask for TO_DATE doesn't match your stated format.

Try this:

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TABLE.timestamp,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
From XXXX.TABLE
WHERE ROWNUM < 10;
```

Comment: That's awesome, and yet I have another wrinkle.  What if I have some nulls?  Where can I put in the NVL?  Or should I use that at all?

Comment: Well, NVL only makes sense if you have a default value you want to substitute.  Do you have such a value?

Comment: If your `timestamp` column has a NULL, the result of this entire expression will also be NULL, which may or may not be a problem for you.